# jQuery set all child LI elements with class of parent LI

Tags: jquery

I want to set all child `<LI>` elements with one of the classes of the parent `<LI>` element. In below example 'parent-style'. Can someone help me in the right direction to accomplish this. Thanks

```
<li class="current sub-menu parent-style"><a id="drop-a" href="/features.aspx">
 <div>Features <span>Out of the Box</span></div>
</a>
<ul class="sub-menuitem sf-js-enabled" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
  <li class="sub-menu"><a id="drop-a" href="/features/feature-01.aspx">
    <div>Feature 01</div>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menuitem sf-js-enabled" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
      <li><a id="drop-a" href="/features/feature-01/feature-01-a.aspx">
        <div>Feature 01 a</div>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a id="drop-a" href="/features/feature-02.aspx">
    <div>Feature 02</div>
    </a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: arrrgh......hmmmm.....question not clear to me Sorry?

Comment: Note that the html shown is invalid: _id_ should be unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to do this in jQuery? Why don't you do it with CSS? (I'm assuming that it is for styling as the class is 'parent-*style*').

```
.parent-style ul li{
    /* styles */
}
```

Comment: Completely missed this or made a mistake trying and got convinced it had to be done with jQuery stuff. Thanks for your clear view! Although the below would also work fine as a jQuery option.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("li.parent-style").find ("li").addClass("parent-style");
```

That should be self-explanatory...

Answer (score 2):

The question really isn't clear what you want, but to add a class to all `<li>` elements under your list, you can do this:

```
$('#listId').find("li").addClass("parent-style");
```